# Is there a way to optimize the initial value of an ODE using optim in R?

Tags: r, optimization

I'd want to optimize a value (`numcaseswk0`) in `R` using `optim`. This value however is not a parameter of the ODE - only an initial value.

The code shown below attempts to do this but the optimization procedure constantly fails and just produces the upper bound provided by the user. I suspect that this may be due to the fact that `numcaseswk0` is not one of the parameters of the ODE. I'd be glad if someone could point how I could fix this. Thanks.

```
library(deSolve)

### ODE FUNCTION

HAVODE <- function(t, states, parameters){
  with(as.list(c(states,parameters)),
       {
         N    <- S + L + Z + I + R
         dS <- -beta * S * (I/N) 
         dL <-  beta * S * (I/N) - (1/durL)*L
         dI <-  (1/durL)*L +(1/durRel)*R - (1/durI)*I             
         dZ <- (1-propRelapse)*(1/durI)*I
         dR <- propRelapse*(1/durI)*I - (1/durRel)*R 
         return(list(c(dS, dL, dI, dZ, dR)))
       })
}

### COST FUNCTION

calib_function <- function(x, parameters,observed.){

  ## Variable to be optimized

  numcaseswk0 <- x

  initpop = parameters[1]
  durL = parameters[2]
  durI = parameters[3]
  fracImmune = parameters[4]
  durRel = parameters[5]
  propRelapse = parameters[6]
  probdetec = parameters[7]
  beta  = parameters[8]

  ## Starting values for states 
  S. = (1-fracImmune)*initpop
  L. = numcaseswk0              # ***  I want this value to be optimized
  I. = 0
  Z. = fracImmune*initpop
  R. = 0  
  states = c(S=S., L= L. , I=I.,  Z=Z.,   R=R.)

  ## Parameters to be fed into ODE solver
  parameters1 = c(durL = durL, durI = durI,durRel = durRel, propRelapse = propRelapse,  beta = beta  )                 
  tspan = seq(0, length(observed.)+10); 
  # Run the ODE solver
  result <- data.frame(ode(y = states, times = tspan,  func = HAVODE,  parms = parameters1))

  # Calculating model response (number of detected incident cases)

  IncDetec <- probdetec *((1/durL)*result[, 3] + (1/durRel)*result[, 6])

  model_response <- IncDetec[-1][1:length(observed.)]     # exclude initial week


  # Calculate negative log likelihood of model responses

  NLLK <- -sum(dpois(x = floor(model_response), lambda = observed., log = TRUE ))

  if (NLLK == Inf){

    NLLK = 999999    # if NLLK is infinity, replace by a large number
  }
  return(NLLK)  
}

## vector of starting values
x0 <- 2
## set lower and upper bounds for these variables
upper <- 10
lower <- 1

## Call the cost function with optim

calib_parameters <- c(135722, 9.2088, 2.6047, 0.47, 3.930, 7.21, 0.094, 0.517)

optimization_results <- optim(par=x0, lower = lower,  upper = upper, method = 'Brent', fn = calib_function, parameters = calib_parameters,  observed. =  abs(rnorm(50, mean=6, sd=3)))
```

Running the code above gives:

```
> optimization_results

$par
[1] 1.000001

$value
[1] 113463174144

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

The estimate produced by `optim` is the value of the lower bound provided (`lower=1`). You may also notice that there are no function evaluations. Why is the optimization not working for `numcaseswk0`?

Comment: it doesn't look like you've given us a [mcve]?  It will be hard to solve this just by staring at the code ...

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, thanks for pointing out the fact that the question needed to be reframed. I have done exactly this, ensuring that I provided as much as is needed to reproduce the problem. I'd appreciate if you could take a second look.

Comment: I tried it once again, but the code seems still missing some parts. When I run it, I get:

`Error in seq.default(length(observed.), et, length.out = numsteps + 1) : 
  object 'numsteps' not found`

Comment: @tpetzoldt, you are right; I had `numsteps` already stored in R's memory. The code has however  been edited now so you won't experience errors when you re-run.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Error in fn(par, ...) : object 'result_df' not found

Comment: @tpetzoldt well, you are right again and I'm sorry about that. Fixed (now it's real).

Answer (score 0):

As Ben already points out, the code example was not reproducible. Maybe it helps you, if I post a code snippet from one of our tutorial examples taken from http://desolve.r-forge.r-project.org/user2014/examples/FME/fit_twocomp.svg

The example uses package FME, that wraps optim (and other optimizers) and provides some additional support.

```
### ============================================================================
### code snippet from the useR!2014 (Los Angeles) tutorial
###
### Copyright tpetzoldt, license: GPL >= 2.0
### more see: 
###   http://desolve.r-forge.r-project.org/user2014/examples/FME/fit_twocomp.svg
### ============================================================================
library(deSolve)
library(FME)

## A two compartment pharmacokinetic model
twocomp <- function (time, y, parms, ...) {
  with(as.list(c(parms, y)), {
    dCL <- kFL * CF - kLF * CL - ke * CL  # concentration in liver
    dCF <-    kLF * CL  - kFL * CF        # concentration in fat
    list(c(dCL, dCF))
  })
}
parms <- c(ke = 0.2,    kFL = 0.1,  kLF = 0.05)
times <- seq(0, 40, length=200)
y0      <-  c(CL = 1, CF = 0)
out <- ode(y0, times, twocomp, parms)

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
## data in database format
## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
dat2 <- data.frame(
  label = rep(c("CL", "CF"), each=8),  # must be the first column
  time = rep(seq(0, 28, 4), 2),
  value = c(1.31,  0.61,  0.49,  0.41,  0.20,  0.12,  0.16,  0.21,
            0.001, 0.041, 0.050, 0.039, 0.031, 0.025, 0.017, 0.012)
)

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
## fit parameters and initial values
## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

parms <- c(CL = 1.0, CF = 0.0, ke = 0.2,    kFL = 0.1,  kLF = 0.05)

cost <- function(p, data, ...) {
  yy <- p[c("CL", "CF")]           # initial values
  pp <-  p[c("ke", "kFL", "kLF")]  # start parameters
  out  <-  ode(yy, times, twocomp, pp)
  modCost(out, data, y="value", ...)
}

## The default Marq optimizer fails here, so we use another, e.g. Port        
fit6  <- modFit(f = cost, p = parms, data=dat2, weight="std",
                lower=rep(0, 5), upper=c(2,2,1,1,1), method="Port")

summary(fit6)        
y0 <- coef(fit6)[c("CL", "CF")]
pp <- coef(fit6)[c("ke", "kFL", "kLF")]
out6 <- ode(y0, times, twocomp, pp)

plot(out, out6, obs=dat2)
```

Comment: thanks for this. In the snippet you have provided, the parameters being optimized are parameters of the ODE, unlike the problem I have presented. What do you do when for instance `ke` (used in your code)  is not a parameter in the ODE??  In my case, I want to optimize 'numcaseswk0` which is only an initial value.

Comment: The example optimizes both, parameters (pp) and **initial values** (yy) of the ode model. For the optimizer and the **cost** function, both appear are "parameters" (parms).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is something wrong with your model specification. The optimizer runs correctly (in a technical sense) and the optimal parameter **is** zero.

Please see comments, what was changed:

- bigger penalty value
- re-scaling of the cost value to a feasible range
- some manual test calls to your cost function
- a few cat() functions that may help for debugging
- note also that the "dot" syntax (L., R., etc.) is not necessary

The following may be still not what you want, but should hopefully help to get it running. Good luck!

```
    library(deSolve)

    ### ODE FUNCTION

    HAVODE <- function(t, states, parameters){
      with(as.list(c(states,parameters)),
           {
             N    <- S + L + Z + I + R
             #cat("N=", N, "\n")
             dS <- -beta * S * (I/N) 
             dL <-  beta * S * (I/N) - (1/durL)*L
             dI <-  (1/durL)*L +(1/durRel)*R - (1/durI)*I             
             dZ <- (1-propRelapse)*(1/durI)*I
             dR <- propRelapse*(1/durI)*I - (1/durRel)*R 
             return(list(c(dS, dL, dI, dZ, dR)))
           })
    }

    ### COST FUNCTION

    calib_function <- function(x, parameters,observed.){

      ## Variable to be optimized
      #cat("x=", x, "\n")

      numcaseswk0 <- x

      initpop = parameters[1]
      durL = parameters[2]
      durI = parameters[3]
      fracImmune = parameters[4]
      durRel = parameters[5]
      propRelapse = parameters[6]
      probdetec = parameters[7]
      beta  = parameters[8]

      ## Starting values for states 
      S. = (1-fracImmune)*initpop
      L. = numcaseswk0              # ***  I want this value to be optimized
      I. = 0
      Z. = fracImmune*initpop
      R. = 0  
      states = c(S=S., L= L. , I=I.,  Z=Z.,   R=R.)
      #cat(states, "\n")

      ## Parameters to be fed into ODE solver
      parameters1 = c(durL = durL, durI = durI,durRel = durRel, propRelapse = propRelapse,  beta = beta  )                 
      tspan = seq(0, length(observed.)+10); 
      # Run the ODE solver
      result <- data.frame(ode(y = states, times = tspan,  func = HAVODE,  parms = parameters1))

      # Calculating model response (number of detected incident cases)

      IncDetec <- probdetec *((1/durL)*result[, 3] + (1/durRel)*result[, 6])

      model_response <- IncDetec[-1][1:length(observed.)]     # exclude initial week


      # Calculate negative log likelihood of model responses

      NLLK <- -sum(dpois(x = floor(model_response), lambda = observed., log = TRUE ))

      ## tpe: set it to a really large value
      if (!is.finite(NLLK)){
        NLLK = 0.1 * .Machine$double.xmax    # if NLLK is infinity, replace by a large number
      }

      ## tpe: re-scale return value to a numerically feasible range
      return(NLLK * 1e-10)  
    }

    ## vector of starting values
    x0 <- 2
    ## set lower and upper bounds for these variables
    upper <- 10
    lower <- 0

    ## Call the cost function with optim

    calib_parameters <- c(135722, 9.2088, 2.6047, 0.47, 3.930, 7.21, 0.094, 0.517)

    ## tpe: reproducible comparison data
    set.seed(42)
    observed <- abs(rnorm(50, mean=6, sd=3))

    ## test manually
    calib_function(1, calib_parameters, observed)
    calib_function(0, calib_parameters, observed)
    calib_function(10, calib_parameters, observed)

    ## tpe: we see that zero *is* the best among these

    ## optimize automatically
    optimization_results <- optim(par=x0, lower = lower,  upper = upper, 
                                  method = 'L-BFGS-B', fn = calib_function, 
                                  parameters = calib_parameters,  
                                  observed. =  observed,
                                  control=list(trace=TRUE))


    optimization_results
    ## tpe: optimized par is again zero, that confirms the manual test
```

Comment: thanks very much for this! At least, the optimizer is running correctly now. I expect `numcaseswk0` to be in the range of (1,3) and so as you rightly said, I might have to recheck the model. The truth is I've done this several times already. Actually,  the same ODE produces the expected results in MATLAB and so still a mystery why it's not doing same in R. Anyways, thanks again for your help :)